# Objective-C initialize (static method) called more that once?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, initialization, global-variables, autorelease

I have code similar to this in Objective-C:

```
SubclassOfNSObject *GlobalVariableThatShouldNeverChange;

@implementation MyClass

+(void) initialize
{
    [super initialize];
    GlobalVariableThatShouldNeverChange = [[SubclassOfNSObject alloc] init];
    // Change more stuff with GlobalVariableThatShouldNeverChange
}

@end
```

I have this referenced throughout code, and the pointer to this should never change because I am using it everywhere through my code.
The problem is, that when I run my tests using `GHUnit`, I have odd problems with the `GlobalVariableThatShouldNeverChange`'s pointer being changed (i.e. It is being reinitialized. I had a problem with the variable being released via the autorelease pool and that is fixed, and I have a workaround for this problem, but I would like to know ***why***?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say:

> The runtime sends initialize to each class in a program exactly one time just before the class, *or any class that inherits from it*.

The recommended approach is:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    if (self == [GHUnit class]) {

        /* put initialization code here */

    }
}
```

Also note the following recommendation from the documentation:

> … you should typically not send `initialize` to `super` in your implementation.

Comment: Ok, so I forgot the `self == Superclass`, thank you! And do you have to have `[super initialize]`?

Comment: That is interesting, I did not know that. It also means a superclass can actually find out at run-time which sub-classes it has.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is yes, `+initialize` can be called more than once.

Bill Bumgarner wrote up a good article on his blog about this.  See [+initialize Can Be Executed Multiple Times (+load not so much)](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/06/iniailize-can-be-executed-multiple-times-load-not-so-much/)

Comment: Ok..I was not doing any heavy lifting, only allocating global variables..thank you, it has taught me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To add up on dreamlax' answer: Beware that you might have subclasses without explicitly creating them, i.e. if you are using KVO, a subclass will be created on-the-fly (which in turn will call initialize again), and all your instances are being changed to this very class.