# Implement alloc on a singleton

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'd like to have a singleton in my system but rather than have callers access it via some kind of 'sharedInstance' method, I'd like them to be able to be unaware that they are using a singleton, in other words, I'd like the callers to be able to say:

```
MyClass *dontKnowItsASingleton = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

To accomplish this, I've tried overriding alloc as follows:

```
// MyClass.m

static MyClass *_sharedInstance;

+ (id)alloc {

    if (!_sharedInstance) {
        _sharedInstance = [super alloc];
    }
    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

My question is: is this okay?  It seems to work, but I've never overridden alloc before.  Also, if it's okay, could I always use this technique, rather than dispatch_once approach I have been doing?  ...

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {

    static SnappyTV *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: It seems fine, however I'm not sure about thread safety. (Minor terminology fixup: you subclass a class, e. g. `NSObject`, when you redefine a method, that's called "overriding".)

Comment: alloc actually calls allocWithZone:, you should probably over ride that.

Comment: @danh Keep in mind that this means `init` will be called repeatedly on the same object.  If you're using ARC, [multiple calls to `init` on the same object is undefined behavior](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics-of-init).  Even if that's ok with you (other classes like `NSString` do it), make sure your `init` method handles being called repeatedly.

Comment: wow.  excellent point, Rob.  I'm going to post an answer with these suggestions for others to find

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @H2CO3 mentioned, your method of going about producing singletons is acceptable, however not threadsafe.  The more traditional approach is to wrap your assignment and comparison in an `@synchronized` block so multiple thread access is reduced, however overriding `+alloc` is not the best way of going about implementing an already shaky pattern.

Comment: I always think about rewriting singletons as class methods, however it feels quirky. I don't like class methods.

Comment: @H2CO3 Well that's what they should be.  I guess this variation of the pattern unsettles me because you can easily get confused as to what is a singleton and what isn't without seeing the code properly.  I guess it's useful in some rare edge-case situations, but...

Comment: Okay - thanks @CodaFi.  Is it okay to use the class itself as the lock  token?

Comment: `self` is sufficient.  I don't believe you can literally use the class as the lock token without some ugly casting.

Comment: Great.  Thanks much.  (self is the class in +alloc)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should take advantage of the initialize method:

```
+ (void) initialize
{
    _sharedInstance= [[self alloc]init];
}


+ (id)sharedInstance 
{
    return _sharedIntsance;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that +initialize can be called multiple times (implicitly of course).  And I do hope _sharedInstance is a static global and that you are checking for it's existance, otherwise you'll have an N-ton.

Comment: initialize gets called once by the runtime, then if a programmer seeks troubles instead of calling initialize can do this: strcpy(0,"Crash");

Comment: Perhaps you should see this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910187/objective-c-initialize-static-method-called-more-that-once

Comment: Thanks @Ramy - also, I'm looking for a safe way to let outsiders use alloc and still have a singleton.  Not sure I see how this addresses that.

Answer (score 1):

In case others come looking, here's a solution that I think integrates all of the good advice:

```
+ (id)alloc {

    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!_sharedInstance) {
            _sharedInstance = [super alloc];
        }
        return _sharedInstance;
    }
}

- (id)init {

    @synchronized(self) {
        static BOOL init = NO;
        if (!init) {
            init = YES;
            self = [super init];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks to @H2CO3 for the thread safety issue, @CodaFi for the thread safety prescription and to @Rob Mayoff for dangers with init under arc.  I got helped by the best and the brightest today!

Comment: It might be better to override `allocWithZone:` instead of `alloc`. It is certainly better to use `dispatch_once` instead of `@synchronized(self)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119042/why-does-apple-recommend-to-use-dispatch-once-for-implementing-the-singleton-pat